# Group and summarize data with countif calculation

Tags: r, dplyr

Imagine having the following table called DT

```
ID    Path   Status
AA    XXX    Completed
AB    XXX    Completed
AC    XXX    In progress
AD    XYY    Completed
AE    XYY    In progress
```

I want to group this table by Path and count (1) the amount of unique ID's and (2) the amount of unique ID's with the status 'Completed' (there are no duplicate ID's in the original table DT)

I tried the following code:

```
DT_Grouped <- DT %>%
     group_by(Path) %>%
     summarise(CountComplete = sum(DT$Status == "Completed"), Count=n())
```

This gives the following result:

```
Path   CountComplete   Count
XXX    3               3
XYY    3               2
```

CountComplete always gives the total amount of unique ID's with the status complete; not grouped by path. Which is logical as the calculation is referring to the original table and not the grouped dataset.

How should I adapt the code in order for CountComplete to group according to Path?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that we are getting the full dataset column with `DT$` instead of he 'Status' values within each group

```
sum(DT$Status == "Completed")
     ^^^^
```

it should be

```
library(dplyr)
DT_Grouped <- DT %>%
     group_by(Path) %>%
     summarise(CountComplete = sum(Status == "Completed"), Count=n())

DT_Grouped
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#   Path  CountComplete Count
#   <chr>         <int> <int>
#1 XXX               2     3
#2 XYY               1     2
```

---

If it is a `data.table`, the corresponding method would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)[, .(CountComplete = sum(Status == "Completed"), Count = .N), by = Path]
```

#### data

```
DT <- structure(list(ID = c("AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE"), Path = c("XXX", 
"XXX", "XXX", "XYY", "XYY"), Status = c("Completed", "Completed", 
"In progress", "Completed", "In progress")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```